# VSCode: difference "create branch" and "create branch from"

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When trying to create a new branch, from an existing one, I'm faced with these two options:

1. `+ Create branch...`
2. `+ Create branch from...`

I don't really understand the difference between these two options.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Both commands are used to create new branches and switch to the branch after successfully created. But

1. `+ Create branch...` will **create a new branch from the current branch** you are working on.
2. `+ Create branch from...` will **create a new branch from some other branch** in the git repository.

Comment: makes sense, was afraid something else would happen under the hood ; thanks

Comment: @ted, if you want to check what happen "under the hood", you can always use `Output` (ctrl+shift+u). There you will see what git commands have been used.

Comment: More specifically, "Create branch" will crate branch from HEAD. Which is not necessarily on a branch. May have been a detached HEAD.

Answer (score 4):

I would guess the first creates a branch from the point you are working from at the time... on the other one, you specify where from.

Comment: I'd say *Create branch* is equivalent to *Create branch from... HEAD* :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Git: Create Branch command lets you quickly create a new branch. Just provide the name of your new branch and VS Code will create the branch and switch to it. If you choose to Create new branch from..., you'll get an extra prompt that allows you to specify which commit the new branch should be pointing to.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview